# JSON string from NSDictionary having file path

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, nsstring, sbjson

I am working on the app in which I store the file name and file path in NSDictionary. My dictionary like,

```
Dict Path : {
    background = "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/6118A03F-345B-42D5-AC19-25F6D9AC4484/Documents/background.caf";
    bgMusic = "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/6118A03F-345B-42D5-AC19-25F6D9AC4484/Documents/bgMusic.caf";
}
```

It's works fine, but when I tried to convert the dictionary in JSON string,

```
NSString *strPathForSong = [json stringWithObject:dictPath];
        NSLog(@"path sting : %@",strPathForSong);
```

it returns null string. So is there any way to convert dictionary having "/" string into json string?? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please provide the source code of how you are trying to convert NSDictionary to JSON ?

Comment: I already mention in my question. please check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The path separators shouldn't be a problem when converting your dictionary to a JSON string.
Your sample doesn't show the type & initialization of your `json` variable but you can obtain a JSON representation from your dict the following way:

```
NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{ @"background": @"file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/6118A03F-345B-42D5-AC19-25F6D9AC4484/Documents/background.caf",
                            @"bgMusic": @"file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/6118A03F-345B-42D5-AC19-25F6D9AC4484/Documents/bgMusic.caf"};
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:nil];
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Dict:%@", jsonString);
```

This works fine here (including proper escaping for the path separators in the log line)

Comment: it works fine with your given jsonDict, but when I replace the name of dicationary for NSData, it gets crash, and gives error "reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSURL)'".

Comment: It seems your paths are stored as NSURL objects in the dictionary. Convert them to strings first with [NSURLobject absoluteString].